# Getting customview from another application at runtime

Tags: android, class, import, runtime, custom-view

I am struggling with the idea of getting `CustomView` from another application. Lets say I have two applications A and B. I know package name of `CustomView`, for example `com.applicationb.CustomView`. Is it possible to create an Object of this Class in application A at runtime?

My aim is to find a way to create `CustomViews` and being able to show them in my application. But I want them (views) to be a separate apk, which may be published to Android Market, and downloaded as some kind of extension.

`CustomView` would only display somekind of animation on screen (for example falling leaves). It would not work on any data in first application.

### Edit

I found something like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
Class c = Class.forName(package_name);
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod(method_name);
m.setAccessible(true);
Canvas can= (Canvas) m.invoke(null, null); // since there are no parameters, and called function is static
```

I hope this will work. I let you know.

Comment: No you can't access 'views' but you can start an `Activity` contained in another app using `startActivity(Intent intent)`. This is fairly basic stuff - I suggest you read about Application Fundamentals - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Comment: I don't want to use any of activities or services from another package. I would only like to use one function for example getCanvas(), which would return canvas to my application. Idea behind this is that other developer could make it own code behind drawing canvas and i would draw it in my application activity.

Comment: Why don't you use an android library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I promissed here is result.

```
String packageName = "com.exapmle.sth";
String className = "com.exapmle.sth.CustomView";

String apkName = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(
    packageName, 0).sourceDir;
PathClassLoader myClassLoader = new dalvik.system.PathClassLoader(
    apkName, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
Class<?> handler = Class.forName(className, true, myClassLoader);
Constructor[] m = handler.getConstructors();
for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    if (m[i].getName().contains("CustomView")) {
        animation = (View)m[i].newInstance(new Object[] { this });
        rootRL.addView(animation, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    }
}
```

With this code it is possible to get View from application B from using application A.